# Как работать с таблицей b_option в административном скрипте модуля в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Разрабатываю модуль, работа в котором ведется с таблицей `b_option` через методы класса `Option::set()`, `Option::get()`.

Использовал для сохранения и вывода функции `__AdmSettingsDrawRow($MODULE_ID, $option)` и `__AdmSettingsSaveOptions($MODULE_ID, $aTab['OPTIONS'])`. Это все внутри модуля в файле `options.php`.

Возникла необходимость вынести настройки в административный скрипт. Данные функции там перестали работать.

Вопрос: как их заставить работать и, если это не возможно, как внутри скрипта работать с настройками, если они у меня, как и описано везде в документации, описаны в массиве:

```
$aTabs = array(
array(
    'DIV' => 'my_options',
    'TAB' => Loc::getMessage("MAIN_TAB_SET"),
    'TITLE' => Loc::getMessage("MAIN_TAB_TITLE_SET"),
    'OPTIONS' => array(
        "Основные настройки",
        array('address',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_ADDRESS"),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "ADDRESS"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('phone',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_PHONE"),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "PHONE"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('email',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_EMAIL"),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "EMAIL"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('copyright',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_COPYRIGHT"),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "COPYRIGHT"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('logo',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_LOGO"),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "LOGO"),
            array('file'),
        ),
        array('delete_logo',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_LOGO_DELETE"),
            "N",
            array('checkbox'),
        ),

        "Ссылки на социальные сети",
        array('note' => 'Укажите ссылки на сообщества магазина в социальных сетях.'),
        array('viber_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_VIBER_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "VIBER_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('skype_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_SKYPE_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "SKYPE_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('telegram_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_TELEGRAM_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "TELEGRAM_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('telegram_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_BEHANCE_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "BEHANCE_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('vk_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_VK_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "VK_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('instagram_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_INSTAGRAM_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "INSTAGRAM_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('note' => 'Для WhatsApp укажите номер телефона и сообщение, которое будет автоматически подставляться при отправке первого сообщения.'),
        array('whatsapp_number',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_WHATSAPP_NUMBER'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "WHATSAPP_NUMBER"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('whatsapp_message',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_WHATSAPP_MESSAGE'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "WHATSAPP_MESSAGE"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('twitter_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_TWITTER_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "TWITTER_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
        array('facebook_link',
            Loc::getMessage('REFERENCES_FACEBOOK_LINK'),
            Option::get(ADMIN_MODULE_NAME, "FACEBOOK_LINK"),
            array('text', 30),
        ),
    )
),
array(
    'DIV' => 'general',
    'TAB' => "Главная",
    'TITLE' => "Главная",
    'OPTIONS' => array(
        array('note' => 'Выберите блоки, которые будут отображаться на главной.'),
        array('advantage_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_ADVANTAGE_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('sections_catalog_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_SECTIONS_CATALOG_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('elements_catalog_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_ELEMENTS_CATALOG_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('sales_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_SALES_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('articles_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_ARTICLES_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('about_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_ABOUT_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('brands_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_BRANDS_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
        array('instagram_block',
            Loc::getMessage("REFERENCES_INSTAGRAM_BLOCK"),
            null,
            array('checkbox'),
        ),
    )
)
```

);

Comment: так как тут не весь кусок кода, уточню, вы по этой инструкции делали: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=101&LESSON_ID=3434

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно, именно по этой инструкции.